# What are good chess tournaments that are FIDE rated in China for foreigners?

Tags: tournament

What are good FIDE rated tournaments in China? I'm currently a FIDE class B and would like to play up. What would be some tournament recommendations and how would I register?

Answer (score 1):

FIDE's worldwide calendar of tournament events normally lists tournaments around the world, but for some reason no tournaments located in China appear. The Chinese Chess Federation has this [website](http://chess.sport.org.cn/), which carries notices of future tournaments.